# create getListof(int n) Function in deluge scripting

Tags: zoho-deluge

I need a solution for this question using deluge scripting

Input : n =5
Output:[1,2,3,4,5]

create getListof(int n) Function

Problem Statement
Create  a function which takes a integer number ‘n’ and returns a list of size n

Additional info
The content of the returning list doesn’t matter
It can be a sequential 1, 2, 3, 4 or  a list of same character  etc

Input / Output
If input n = 5 , the function should return a list of size 5 ie. [x,x,x,x,x ]
Where x can be any character / number / special character / even none